# Factory Girl create objects but objects not found in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm using cucumber with Factory Girl and here is the mysterious problem,

in my cucumber steps :

```
fact = Factory.create(:fact,
                   :factable_type => "type_#{i}",
                   :factable_id => i.to_s,
                   :factable_action => "action_#{i}",
                   :priority => "1"
    )
```

When I check in debug mode with ruby mine I have a fact with an ID but if I check in my IRB test console :

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :011 > Fact.all
 => []
```

Of course when I want to run my tests and check presence of objects in the database, my tests fail because of that. Do you have any idea ?

Here is my env.rb file :

```
# IMPORTANT: This file is generated by cucumber-rails - edit at your own peril.
# It is recommended to regenerate this file in the future when you upgrade to a 
# newer version of cucumber-rails. Consider adding your own code to a new file 
# instead of editing this one. Cucumber will automatically load all features/**/*.rb
# files.

require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'fakeweb'
require "factory_girl"

# Add this to load Capybara integration:
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

require File.expand_path('../../../spec/vcr_setup.rb', __FILE__)
require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'cucumber/rspec/doubles'

require 'email_spec'
require 'email_spec/cucumber'

# require 'cucumber/thinking_sphinx/external_world'
# Cucumber::ThinkingSphinx::ExternalWorld.new

# Capybara defaults to XPath selectors rather than Webrat's default of CSS3. In
# order to ease the transition to Capybara we set the default here. If you'd
# prefer to use XPath just remove this line and adjust any selectors in your
# steps to use the XPath syntax.
Capybara.default_selector = :css

Capybara.run_server = true #Whether start server when testing
Capybara.default_selector = :xpath #default selector , you can change to :css
Capybara.default_wait_time = 2 #When we testing AJAX, we can set a default wait time
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false #Ignore hidden elements when testing, make helpful when you hide or show elements using javascript
Capybara.javascript_driver = :culerity #default driver when you using @javascript tag

# By default, any exception happening in your Rails application will bubble up
# to Cucumber so that your scenario will fail. This is a different from how 
# your application behaves in the production environment, where an error page will 
# be rendered instead.
#
# Sometimes we want to override this default behaviour and allow Rails to rescue
# exceptions and display an error page (just like when the app is running in production).
# Typical scenarios where you want to do this is when you test your error pages.
# There are two ways to allow Rails to rescue exceptions:
#
# 1) Tag your scenario (or feature) with @allow-rescue
#
# 2) Set the value below to true. Beware that doing this globally is not
# recommended as it will mask a lot of errors for you!
#
ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

# Remove/comment out the lines below if your app doesn't have a database.
# For some databases (like MongoDB and CouchDB) you may need to use :truncation instead.
#begin
#  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
#rescue NameError
#  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
#end

# You may also want to configure DatabaseCleaner to use different strategies for certain features and scenarios.
# See the DatabaseCleaner documentation for details. Example:
#
#   Before('@no-txn,@selenium,@culerity,@celerity,@javascript') do
#     DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[widgets]}
#   end
#
#   Before('~@no-txn', '~@selenium', '~@culerity', '~@celerity', '~@javascript') do
#     DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
#   end
#

## Sets up the Rails environment for Cucumber
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../config/environment')
require 'cucumber/rails/world'
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures
#
##Seed the DB

Fixtures.reset_cache

fixtures_to_load = ['facts','roles', 'user_types']

fixtures_folder = File.join(Rails.root, 'features', 'fixtures')
fixtures = Dir[File.join(fixtures_folder, '*.yml')].map {|f| File.basename(f, '.yml') }
fixtures.delete_if { |fx| !fixtures_to_load.index(fx)}
Fixtures.create_fixtures(fixtures_folder, fixtures)

Before do
    Capybara.default_host = 'http://site.local'

  NetworkConfig.initialize(:id => 1)
end
```

and in my factories.rb file :

```
require "factory_girl"

Factory.define :fact do |i|
  i.factable_type "Follow"
  i.factable_id   "1"
  i.factable_action     "create"
  i.is_processed  "false"
  i.processing_has_started "false"
  i.processing_has_ended "false"
  i.priority "1"
end
```

Comment: How are you accessing irb? ruby-debug? rails console?

Comment: When you say IRB do you mean a separate irb console? If so then this is normal: since you're wrapping each story in a transaction other database connections can't see the uncommitted changes

Comment: Your Rails environment might also be wrong.

Comment: Right but if I use Factory to create my objects in one step and then do a query to my database in a following step should I find those objects ?

Comment: Are you sure it's creating the object? It could be failing validation?

Comment: I checked that using my_object.is_valid? method and it appears it's not the problem here, any other idea ?

Comment: Is the step that's checking for the objects a controller action triggered via Capybara? If so then it won't be able to see the records either because Capybara's server has its own db connection and the transaction hasn't committed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **rails console** or **rails c** command to check the data from your factory. I think you need to switch the environment like this:

```
$ rails c
irb(main):010>ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection "test"
irb(main):010> Fact.all
```